# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client tbpassword="9<Grfs-&3E"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Net, I am getting an error saying

"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" when I am entering a password with special characters "<" and ">" in it,
I found some solutions on online saying add validrequest="false" and requestValidationMode="2.0" I did add both the statements in the web.config file and over the top of the page 
my web config looks like this

`<system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="TARGET.DRP.ADMINS, TARGET.DRP.BUSINESS_ADMINS, TARGET.DRP.DEVICE_MNGRS, TARGET.DRP.USERS, TARGET.DRP.MANUFACTURERS"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
      <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    </system.web>`

And also this is showing up only if the password has "<" or ">" but if the password has both "<" and ">" it is working fine.
Is there any way to resolve this.

Thank you..

Comment: You lost the bet.. though

Comment: If you can read the question properly I clearly mentioned that I found some stuff saying validrequest="false" and requestValidationMode="2.0" and I also said I added both the statements...

Answer (score 1):

If you're submiting the form with a GET it won't work unless you encode the values-

Comment: Isn’t `Request.Form` POST?

Comment: No, you can choose the method

Comment: The error pops up after hitting ok button.. but the thing is it is not even hitting the click event... I didnot use any forms, I used a Label and textbox with a textmode="password"

Answer (score 0):

Place the `validateRequest="false"` on your `web.config` as:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" ... >
```

This make it work. After that you need to be careful what you render on your page and you have get from users input.

[page element on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I still have this error showing up even after adding the two statements in web.config    <system.web>
      <authorization>       
      </authorization>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
      <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    </system.web>